# Problema con busqueda en datatable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

Actualmente estoy usando el plugin de datatables para listar de una forma dinamica datos de tablas que tengo realizadas para un sistema que estoy trabajando.

Actualmente he leido lo suficiente del plugin y no he tenido muchos problemas para poder usarlo, pero hoy si que me he encontrado con un problema grande. Al tener un datatable para listar personas por un tipo especifico, todo funciona muy bien, me muestra la informacion por el tipo que le estoy indicando (una sola persona en este caso), pero cual es mi sorpresa que al momento de al hacer una busqueda, al colocar la letra "M", automaticamente el datatable me encuentra TODO lo que hay dentro de la tabla personas que comience o contenga la letra M. He buscado pero no encuentro como hacer que se mantenga esa limitante que le tengo para mostrar la informacion para que tambien se mantenga en la busqueda.

El codigo lo tengo de la siguiente forma para mostrar la informacion y para realizar la busqueda:

```
//Ordenacion
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumnas[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".$_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    //Filtracion
    $sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    // Filtrado de columna individual 
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%'";
        }
    }


    //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries

    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM personas p
    INNER JOIN sesion s ON s.personas_cedula=p.cedula 
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";

    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);


    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->fetch_array();
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTabla
    ";
    $rResultTotal = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
    $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->fetch_array();
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
```

Me tiene un tanto preocupado la situacion de la busqueda porque no deberia mostrarse otros datos. Quizas sea algo tonto lo que este pasando, pero realmente no logro como solucionarlo, por eso estoy buscando una ayuda.

Comment: Tiene pinta de estar haciéndolo bien, de sobrescribir $sWhere al hacer una búsqueda con $_GET['sSearch'], ya que le está diciendo que recorra todas las columnas de la tabla con un like. Supongo que es lo que hace cuando buscas.

Comment: Hola @Carmen, pero el problema esta es que si yo le indico a datatables que de la tabla personas (que existen 3 registros Miguel, Doris, Carmen) me muestre solo es que es usuario tipo 1 ($sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1";) me lo hace bien, me muestra a 1 solo registro, que en este caso es Miguel. Pero al realizar una busqueda, es decir, si coloco C, deberia decirme que no hay coincidencias, y lo q hace es buscarme a todo aquel registro que exista en la tabla personas que contenga la letra C, en este caso, me encuentra a Carmen. ves? y no es lo que quiero porque es un datatable para 1 solo tipo

Comment: Si te he entendido bien, en ese caso tienes que cambiar el apartado '//Filtracion' porque cuando entra por el if en la búsqueda pierde $sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1"; tedrías que concatenar esta opción al sWhere que se compone en el bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a los comentarios, cuando buscas hace un barrido por las colunmas contruyendo una condición genérica con `like` para el elemento de búsqueda guardao en la variable `$_GET['sSearch']`, y reescribe la condición anterior al bucle.

Para mantener esta condición al hacer una búsqueda debes añadirla concatenándola a los otros elementos. Por ejemplo:

```
//Filtracion
    $sWhere = " WHERE  s.id_tipo = 1";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
        $sWhere .= ' AND s.id_tipo = 1 ';
    }
```

Comment: Perfecto @Carmen, con esto ha funcionado, Ahora si escribo C, ya no aparece Carmen que es otro tipo de usuario distinto a Miguel. Pero ahora tengo un detalle, si escribo carmen, es como que en el fondo de todo la encontrara, es decir, escribo Carmen, o Doris, y no me dice "no se ha encontrado coincidentes", sino que simplemente es como si encontrara lo que escribi, no lo muestra, pero en el fondo del datatable sabe que si existe en la tabla. Que podria estar sucediendo en ese caso?

Comment: Disculpa @Carmen, el comentario anterior ya lo he solucionado, solo fue un error de mi parte de transcripcion ya que no coloque el .= en el sWhere, y ahora que he leido bien, era eso. Muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en ayudarme. Tu respuesta fue la solucion! Saludos.

Comment: De nada, me alegra que lo tengas resuelto. Para eso estamos ;)

Comment: Hola @Carmen, disculpa que vuelva a comentar por acá pero tengo una consulta con respecto a esto mismo pero ahora es al momento de hacer en el sWhere ="WHERE s.id_tipo = 1 OR s.id_tipo = 2"; todo se muestra correctamente, es decir, ambos tipos de usuarios se muestran en el datatables, pero al colocar al final  $sWhere .= ' AND s.id_tipo = 1 OR s.id_tipo = 2 '; me está sucediendo que al buscar los datos del usuario que es tipo 2, me los encuentra perfectamente y solo los de ese tipo, pero al buscar los datos del usuario tipo 1, simplemente me muestra los datos de ambos tipos, es decir,

Comment: no se está ejecutando bien la búsqueda por los datos del usuario tipo 1 porque la tabla queda intacta al escribir cualquier dato del usuario 1 para ejecutar una busqueda. ¿Por que podría pasar eso? Por usar el OR? O porque la condición también debe ir en otro lugar? Intenté poniendo la validación en varios lugares pero no obtuve resultados positivos, por eso he vuelto a mí consulta. De todas formas, yo hice la consulta nuevamente con ese error para un estatus de citas q pasa igual, está en este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94562/error-al-implementar-or-en-busqueda-de-datatable

Comment: Es porque te falta un paréntesis si usas or, sino son dos condiciones independientes, sería 'AND (s.id_tipo=1 OR s.id_tipo=2). Otro modo de hacerlo es sin el or, usando una búsqueda dentro de un intervalo, sería 'AND s.id_tipo IN (1,2)'. Esta última te permite añadir dentro del paréntesis los valores que quieras.

Comment: gracias nuevamente. Los paréntesis era la solución! Lo del IN si no lo sabía y creo que también es mejor para usar. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Saludos

Comment: No hay de que @rodrigo2324