# Error al implementar "OR" en busqueda de datatable

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un sistema de registro de citas donde hago uso de datatables para poder mostrar las citas que tienen un estatus especifico. Todo me ha salido bien hasta que he filtrado el datatable para que me muestre solo las citas que sean de un tipo o de otro tipo (si son citas con estatus 'en espera de confirmacion' o 'reprogramada')

Para poder mostrar los datos, lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
$sWhere = " WHERE  c.idEstatus = 'En espera de Confirmación' OR c.idEstatus = 'Reprogramada'";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
        $sWhere .= "AND c.idEstatus = 'En espera de Confirmación' OR c.idEstatus = 'Reprogramada'";
    }
```

con el  **$sWhere** restrinjo lo que sera visible, hasta ahi todo bien, pero en el momento donde digo

```
$sWhere .= "AND c.idEstatus = 'En espera de Confirmación' OR c.idEstatus = 'Reprogramada'";
```

me esta pasando que al escribir "reprogramada" me busca a todas las reprogramadas, pero al escribir "en espera de confirmacion" me busca las de ese tipo y al mismo tiempo me busca las que estan reprogramadas tambien y no deberia. Esto solamente sucede cuando hago la busqueda y no comprendo porque. Que podria estar sucediendo? 
No se si el problema es el uso del OR.

aparte de lo anterior, poseo tambien:

```
// Filtrado de columna individual 
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumnas) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumnas[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%'";
        }
    }


    //Obtener datos para mostrar SQL queries

    $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumnas))."
    FROM citas c 
    INNER JOIN personas p ON p.cedula = c.personas_cedula 
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";

    $rResult = $mysqli->query($sQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

todo esta bien pero lo que te falta es tener muy en claro como trabaja los OR y los AND te recomiendo que agrupes los OR entre () para que asi TODO ese conjunto resulta Verdadero o Falso si se cumple alguno o ningun de las condicionales, asi como lo haces con el FOR

```
$sWhere .= "AND (c.idEstatus = 'En espera de Confirmación' OR c.idEstatus = 'Reprogramada')";
```

Así estas obligando a que Primero evalué el OR y después pase a realizar la validación con el AND

Comment: Muchas gracias @carloscaliche2, tu respuesta ha sido la solucion a mi consulta!! efectivamente lo que estaba faltando eran los parentesis. Gracias por tu ayuda y pronta respuesta. Saludos!